# Python List Copying

Tags: python, list, function, copy

I have a function that creates an empty list, called `list_set`, and adds a copy of a pre-existing list, 
original_list, so `list_set[0]` is `original_list`.

The function has to copy `list_set[0]`, choose a value at random and manipulate it based on a
pre-existing function, new_sum, and then add this new list as `list_set[1]`.

Similarly, the function has to copy `list_set[1]` (which is NOT THE SAME as
`list_set[0]`), choose a value at random in `list_set[1]` and manipulate it
based on the function new_sum, and add it as `list_set[2]`.

The function has to
do this 300 times.

In my code, I am noticing that the function is creating 300 identical copies of `original_list` and manipulating a value at random in each list.

```
def condition_manipulate(value):
    list_set=[]
    for i in range(0,value):
        new_list=original_list[:]
        i=random.choice(range(len(original_list)))
        new_list[i]=new_sum(new_list[i])
        list_set.append(new_list)
    return list_set
```

How can I fix this code? The help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You want a deep copy. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948032/if-slicing-does-not-create-a-copy-of-a-list-nor-does-list-how-can-i-get-a-real?rq=1

Comment: new_sum is another function that actually does the manipulations

Comment: What is the interface to your new_sum function?.What does it take and what does it return?. Also try to split your call nesting into variables to make the code clearer.Sorry, but your code is very ugly.

Comment: new_sum takes whatever value it takes and creates a matrix multiplication of a numpy array and a list. If new_sum took 45 as an argument, then it would do
numpy.sum(numpy.dot(a[45][:100], initial_conditions[:100], where a is a 100 by 100 matrix and initial_conditions is a list. if the result is greater than zero, then new_sum on 45 equals 1. If the result of new_sum on 45 is less than zero, then it yields a -1

Comment: I think your code is fine. Test your `new_sum` function, it may be the culprit. Also you are overwriting the `i` loop variable in your code, make sure this not a problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the problem with overwriting i, as pointed before, it seems you are in fact always taking original list again. What about something like this:

```
def condition_manipulate(value):
    list_set=[original_list]
    for i in range(0,value):
        new_list=list_set[-1][:]
        i=random.choice(range(len(original_list)))
        new_list[i]=new_sum(new_list[i])
        list_set.append(new_list)
    return list_set
```